# Artemis broker is not announcing itself as backup on RHEL machine

Tags: activemq-artemis, rhel7

I have 5 Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7.7 system with ActiveMQ Artemis brokers installed on each of them. I have configured 1 master and the rest as slaves. The snippet of `broker.xml` for the master broker is as follows:

```xml
<connectors>
   <connector name="mainBrokerConnector">tcp://10.1.144.200:61616</connector>
</connectors>

<discovery-groups>
   <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
      <local-bind-address>10.1.144.200</local-bind-address>
      <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
      <group-port>9876</group-port>
      <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
   </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>
 
<cluster-connections>
   <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <connector-ref>mainBrokerConnector</connector-ref>
      <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
      <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
       <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>1</max-hops>
      <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
   </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>

<broadcast-groups>
   <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
      <local-bind-address>10.1.144.200</local-bind-address>
      <local-bind-port>5432</local-bind-port>
      <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
      <group-port>9876</group-port>
      <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
      <connector-ref>mainBrokerConnector</connector-ref>
   </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>

<ha-policy>
   <replication>
      <master>
        <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
      </master>
   </replication>
</ha-policy>
```

Three of the four backup brokers when started (`./artemis run`) announce themselves as backups. In the logs of the backup brokers I see something like this (hence I know that they are in sync):

```
2020-10-07 14:19:43,480 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221024: Backup server ActiveMQServerImpl::serverUUID=e2fbfd28-04ec-11eb-b49a-005056aded6a is synchronized with live-server.
2020-10-07 14:19:43,768 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221031: backup announced
```

However, the fourth broker starts but does not logs anything about syncing. The `broker.xml` snippet of the fourth broker is as follows

```xml
<connectors>
   <connector name="brokerTwoConnector">tcp://10.1.144.202:61616</connector>
</connectors>

<discovery-groups>
   <discovery-group name="my-discovery-group">
      <local-bind-address>10.1.144.202</local-bind-address>
      <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
      <group-port>9876</group-port>
      <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
   </discovery-group>
</discovery-groups>

<cluster-connections>
   <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
      <connector-ref>brokerTwoConnector</connector-ref>
      <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
      <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
      <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>
      <max-hops>1</max-hops>
      <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="my-discovery-group"/>
   </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>

<broadcast-groups>
   <broadcast-group name="my-broadcast-group">
      <local-bind-address>10.1.144.202</local-bind-address>
      <local-bind-port>5432</local-bind-port>
      <group-address>231.7.7.7</group-address>
      <group-port>9876</group-port>
      <broadcast-period>2000</broadcast-period>
      <connector-ref>brokerTwoConnector</connector-ref>
   </broadcast-group>
</broadcast-groups>

<ha-policy>
   <replication>
      <slave>
        <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
      </slave>
   </replication>
</ha-policy>
```

Rest of the slave brokers have the same configuration except different host IP addresses and connector names. So what is not configured properly that this broker is not syncing with the master broker?

***EDIT***

When I start the culprit broker then following logs appear which shows that its part of a cluster:

```
2020-10-07 16:10:15,525 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server
2020-10-07 16:10:15,572 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: backup Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=true,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
2020-10-07 16:10:15,598 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222162: Moving data directory /opt/brokerTwo/brokerTwo/data/journal to /opt/brokerTwo/brokerTwo/data/journal/oldreplica.2
2020-10-07 16:10:15,631 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
2020-10-07 16:10:15,740 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222007: Security risk! Apache ActiveMQ Artemis is running with the default cluster admin user and default password. Please see the cluster chapter in the ActiveMQ Artemis User Guide for instructions on how to change this.
2020-10-07 16:10:15,749 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 1,073,741,824
2020-10-07 16:10:15,964 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2020-10-07 16:10:15,966 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2020-10-07 16:10:15,967 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2020-10-07 16:10:15,968 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
2020-10-07 16:10:15,968 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
2020-10-07 16:10:15,969 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2020-10-07 16:10:16,203 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2020-10-07 16:10:16,279 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2020-10-07 16:10:17,173 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2020-10-07 16:10:17,201 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2020-10-07 16:10:17,205 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to hawtio 1.5.5 : http://hawt.io/ : Don't cha wish your console was hawt like me? ;-)
2020-10-07 16:10:17,210 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.UploadManager] Using file upload directory: /opt/brokerTwo/brokerTwo/tmp/uploads
2020-10-07 16:10:17,239 INFO  [io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "amq" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2020-10-07 16:10:17,293 INFO  [io.hawt.web.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/opt/brokerTwo/brokerTwo/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
2020-10-07 16:10:17,355 INFO  [io.hawt.web.RBACMBeanInvoker] Using MBean [hawtio:type=security,area=jmx,rank=0,name=HawtioDummyJMXSecurity] for role based access control
```

Comment: Have you already tried to start the fourth broker before other slaves?

Comment: Yes, this is the first thing I tried also after reboot

Comment: I'm curious why you are using 1 master and 4 slaves. That means when all 5 brokers are started you will have 3 completely idle brokers waiting to pair with a master. Keep in mind that a live can only pair with a single backup at a time so there will only be one backup receiving replicated data (hence the 3 completely idle brokers).

Comment: Hello @JustinBertram, I was testing somethings and when I saw this behavior than I got curious. Yes, I know that this is not an ideal configuration but still all N slaves should announce themselves. What if I want to have a back up of slave node as well?

Comment: I could understand a circumstance (albeit rare) where you might want a backup for a backup, and I would expect such a configuration to work. However, four backups seems like a such a rare and bizarre use-case that I'm not really compelled to spend much time diagnosing problems with it. There's only so much time in the day, and there are lots of other higher priority problems to address. I recommend you move forward with a more traditional architecture (e.g. a single live/backup pair), but if your curiosity compels you then dive into the source code. I'd be interested to hear what you find.

Comment: Thank you @JustinBertram, I was waiting for you to respond. For sure, if I look into it and find something then I will share here.

Comment: @JustinBertram are there any specific logs where I can look that why the fourth broker is not announcing backup even if I start Master and this slave only?

Comment: I can't think of anything specific off the top of my head.